# namespace not working in class library c#

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to create a class library using some classes that I created in another project. One of the classes uses images and needs the `System.Drawing` namespace. However, when I try to copy the code from my project into a new class in my class library, I get an error saying *the image object does not exist in the current context*, and

> The type or namespace name "Drawing" does not exist in the namespace System(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

It works fine in the other class as part of the other project. Why would this be?

Comment: Did you add System.Drawing assembly refernce to your project where your new class resides ?

Comment: can you put code of your library project..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make sure that `System.Drawing` is added to the library's assembly references. By default, for class libraries, no Windows Forms assemblies are added.

Answer (score 1):

Yes The problem lies in the References. If you go to your Solution Explorer and expand it, you will see a nested Folder Titled 'References'. Here is where you add the references needed in your project. To add them, simply right click the folder and select add Reference. Once here the reference you need will be in the .Net tab.

Answer (score 0):

In case if a particular .NET reference is not added by default, do that manually:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score -1):

```
using System.Drawing;
```

Write this in top of your class file. then also if u get error right click on reference and add reference of System.Drawing in your project.

Comment: He clearly says the compiler complains when he tries to use the `System.Drawing` namespace. It doesn't matter whether there's a `using` at the top of the file or whether he fully qualifies the names.

Comment: in error message saying that... are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference? SO its either there is no using directive or Assembly reference?  Correct me if i am wrong...

Comment: The fact that the compiler complains about the `Drawing` *type or namespace* not being found indicates that he either already has the `using` statement in the header, or that he uses the `Image` class like `System.Drawing.Image`. In that case he doesn't even need the `using` statement. The compiler doesn't know whether it is a class or a namespace, so it suggests to add the `using` in case `Drawing` was a class or add the reference, in case `Drawing` is a namespace.